# PySpark timeout trying to repartition/write to parquet (Futures timed out after [300 seconds])?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, aws-glue

I am running PySpark (on AWS Glue, if that matters). I am getting timeout errors: (it appears it fail to write to parquet)

The full logs at https://pastebin.com/TmuAcFx7

```
File "script_2019-02-06-02-32-43.py", line 197, in <module>
.parquet("s3://xxx-glue/cleanedFlights")
File "/mnt/yarn/usercache/root/appcache/application_1549418793443_0001/container_1549418793443_0001_01_000001/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/readwriter.py", line 691, in parquet
File "/mnt/yarn/usercache/root/appcache/application_1549418793443_0001/container_1549418793443_0001_01_000001/py4j-0.10.4-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 1133, in __call__
File "/mnt/yarn/usercache/root/appcache/application_1549418793443_0001/container_1549418793443_0001_01_000001/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/utils.py", line 63, in deco
File "/mnt/yarn/usercache/root/appcache/application_1549418793443_0001/container_1549418793443_0001_01_000001/py4j-0.10.4-src.zip/py4j/protocol.py", line 319, in get_return_value
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o246.parquet.
: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted.
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$$anonfun$write$1.apply$mcV$sp(FileFormatWriter.scala:213)
Caused by: org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.errors.package$TreeNodeException: execute, tree:
Exchange hashpartitioning(countryName#24, querydatetime#213, 200)
+- *Project [master_key#588, master_querydatetime#589, Id#180, QueryTaskId#181, QueryOriginPlace#182, queryoutbounddate#334, queryinbounddate#375, QueryCabinClass#185, QueryCurrency#186, Agent#187, QuoteAgeInMinutes#188, Price#189, OutboundLegId#190, InboundLegId#191, outdeparture#416, outarrival#457, OutDuration#194, OutJourneyMode#195, OutStops#196, OutCarriers#197, OutOperatingCarriers#198, NumberOutStops#199, NumberOutCarriers#200, NumberOutOperatingCarriers#201, ... 33 more fields]
+- BatchEvalPython [getInterval(cast(date_format(outdeparture#416, H, Some(Zulu)) as int), 0, 24, 4), getInterval(cast(date_format(indeparture#498, H, Some(Zulu)) as int), 0, 24, 4)], [master_key#588, master_querydatetime#589, Id#180, QueryTaskId#181, QueryOriginPlace#182, queryoutbounddate#334, queryinbounddate#375, QueryCabinClass#185, QueryCurrency#186, Agent#187, QuoteAgeInMinutes#188, Price#189, OutboundLegId#190, InboundLegId#191, outdeparture#416, outarrival#457, OutDuration#194, OutJourneyMode#195, OutStops#196, OutCarriers#197, OutOperatingCarriers#198, NumberOutStops#199, NumberOutCarriers#200, NumberOutOperatingCarriers#201, ... 21 more fields]
+- *Sort [key#250 ASC NULLS FIRST, querydatetime#101 ASC NULLS FIRST], true, 0
+- Exchange rangepartitioning(key#250 ASC NULLS FIRST, querydatetime#101 ASC NULLS FIRST, 200)
+- *Project [key#250 AS master_key#588, querydatetime#101 AS master_querydatetime#589, Id#180, QueryTaskId#181, QueryOriginPlace#182, queryoutbounddate#334, queryinbounddate#375, QueryCabinClass#185, QueryCurrency#186, Agent#187, QuoteAgeInMinutes#188, Price#189, OutboundLegId#190, InboundLegId#191, outdeparture#416, outarrival#457, OutDuration#194, OutJourneyMode#195, OutStops#196, OutCarriers#197, OutOperatingCarriers#198, NumberOutStops#199, NumberOutCarriers#200, NumberOutOperatingCarriers#201, ... 19 more fields]
+- *BroadcastHashJoin [key#250, querydatetime#101], [key#590, querydatetime#213], LeftOuter, BuildRight
:- *Project [key#250, querydatetime#101]
: +- BroadcastNestedLoopJoin BuildRight, Cross
: :- Generate explode(pythonUDF0#1633), false, false, [querydatetime#101]
: : +- BatchEvalPython [generate_date_series(start#94, stop#95)], [start#94, stop#95, pythonUDF0#1633]
: : +- Scan ExistingRDD[start#94,stop#95]
: +- BroadcastExchange IdentityBroadcastMode
: +- *HashAggregate(keys=[key#250], functions=[], output=[key#250])
: +- *HashAggregate(keys=[key#250], functions=[], output=[key#250])
: +- *Sample 0.0, 0.001, false, 7736333241016522154
: +- *GlobalLimit 5000000
: +- Exchange SinglePartition
: +- *LocalLimit 5000000
: +- *Project [concat(outboundlegid#190, -, inboundlegid#191, -, agent#187) AS key#250]
: +- *SortMergeJoin [querydestinationplace#212], [cast(airportId#38 as int)], Inner
: :- *Sort [querydestinationplace#212 ASC NULLS FIRST], false, 0
: : +- Exchange hashpartitioning(querydestinationplace#212, 200)
: : +- *Project [Agent#187, OutboundLegId#190, InboundLegId#191, querydestinationplace#212]
: : +- *SortMergeJoin [agent#187], [id#89], Inner
: : :- *Sort [agent#187 ASC NULLS FIRST], false, 0
: : : +- Exchange hashpartitioning(agent#187, 200)
: : : +- *Project [Agent#187, OutboundLegId#190, InboundLegId#191, querydestinationplace#212]
: : : +- *Filter (isnotnull(agent#187) && isnotnull(querydestinationplace#212))
: : : +- Scan ExistingRDD[Id#180,QueryTaskId#181,QueryOriginPlace#182,QueryOutboundDate#183,QueryInboundDate#184,QueryCabinClass#185,QueryCurrency#186,Agent#187,QuoteAgeInMinutes#188,Price#189,OutboundLegId#190,InboundLegId#191,OutDeparture#192,OutArrival#193,OutDuration#194,OutJourneyMode#195,OutStops#196,OutCarriers#197,OutOperatingCarriers#198,NumberOutStops#199,NumberOutCarriers#200,NumberOutOperatingCarriers#201,InDeparture#202,InArrival#203,... 10 more fields]
: : +- *Sort [id#89 ASC NULLS FIRST], false, 0
: : +- Exchange hashpartitioning(id#89, 200)
: : +- *Project [cast(id#67L as string) AS id#89]
: : +- *Filter (isnotnull(id#67L) && isnotnull(cast(id#67L as string)))
: : +- Scan ExistingRDD[id#67L,name#68,imageurl#69,status#70,optimisedformobile#71,type#72,bookingnumber#73,createdat#74,updatedat#75]
: +- *Sort [cast(airportId#38 as int) ASC NULLS FIRST], false, 0
: +- Exchange hashpartitioning(cast(airportId#38 as int), 200)
: +- *Project [cast(airportId#18L as string) AS airportId#38]
: +- *Filter (isnotnull(airportId#18L) && isnotnull(cast(airportId#18L as string)))
: +- Scan ExistingRDD[airportId#18L,cityId#19L,countryId#20L,airportCode#21,airportName#22,cityName#23,countryName#24]
+- BroadcastExchange HashedRelationBroadcastMode(List(input[34, string, true], input[33, date, true]))
+- *Project [Id#180, QueryTaskId#181, QueryOriginPlace#182, cast(QueryOutboundDate#183 as date) AS queryoutbounddate#334, cast(QueryInboundDate#184 as date) AS queryinbounddate#375, QueryCabinClass#185, QueryCurrency#186, Agent#187, QuoteAgeInMinutes#188, Price#189, OutboundLegId#190, InboundLegId#191, cast(unix_timestamp(OutDeparture#192, yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss, Some(Zulu)) as timestamp) AS outdeparture#416, cast(unix_timestamp(OutArrival#193, yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss, Some(Zulu)) as timestamp) AS outarrival#457, OutDuration#194, OutJourneyMode#195, OutStops#196, OutCarriers#197, OutOperatingCarriers#198, NumberOutStops#199, NumberOutCarriers#200, NumberOutOperatingCarriers#201, cast(unix_timestamp(InDeparture#202, yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss, Some(Zulu)) as timestamp) AS indeparture#498, cast(unix_timestamp(InArrival#203, yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss, Some(Zulu)) as timestamp) AS inarrival#539, ... 15 more fields]
+- *Sample 0.0, 0.001, false, 7736333241016522154
+- *GlobalLimit 5000000
+- Exchange SinglePartition
+- *LocalLimit 5000000
+- *Project [Id#180, QueryTaskId#181, QueryOriginPlace#182, QueryOutboundDate#183, QueryInboundDate#184, QueryCabinClass#185, QueryCurrency#186, Agent#187, QuoteAgeInMinutes#188, Price#189, OutboundLegId#190, InboundLegId#191, OutDeparture#192, OutArrival#193, OutDuration#194, OutJourneyMode#195, OutStops#196, OutCarriers#197, OutOperatingCarriers#198, NumberOutStops#199, NumberOutCarriers#200, NumberOutOperatingCarriers#201, InDeparture#202, InArrival#203, ... 15 more fields]
+- *SortMergeJoin [querydestinationplace#212], [cast(airportId#38 as int)], Inner
:- *Sort [querydestinationplace#212 ASC NULLS FIRST], false, 0
: +- Exchange hashpartitioning(querydestinationplace#212, 200)
: +- *Project [Id#180, QueryTaskId#181, QueryOriginPlace#182, QueryOutboundDate#183, QueryInboundDate#184, QueryCabinClass#185, QueryCurrency#186, Agent#187, QuoteAgeInMinutes#188, Price#189, OutboundLegId#190, InboundLegId#191, OutDeparture#192, OutArrival#193, OutDuration#194, OutJourneyMode#195, OutStops#196, OutCarriers#197, OutOperatingCarriers#198, NumberOutStops#199, NumberOutCarriers#200, NumberOutOperatingCarriers#201, InDeparture#202, InArrival#203, ... 11 more fields]
: +- *SortMergeJoin [Agent#187], [id#89], Inner
: :- *Sort [Agent#187 ASC NULLS FIRST], false, 0
: : +- Exchange hashpartitioning(Agent#187, 200)
: : +- *Filter (isnotnull(Agent#187) && isnotnull(querydestinationplace#212))
: : +- Scan ExistingRDD[Id#180,QueryTaskId#181,QueryOriginPlace#182,QueryOutboundDate#183,QueryInboundDate#184,QueryCabinClass#185,QueryCurrency#186,Agent#187,QuoteAgeInMinutes#188,Price#189,OutboundLegId#190,InboundLegId#191,OutDeparture#192,OutArrival#193,OutDuration#194,OutJourneyMode#195,OutStops#196,OutCarriers#197,OutOperatingCarriers#198,NumberOutStops#199,NumberOutCarriers#200,NumberOutOperatingCarriers#201,InDeparture#202,InArrival#203,... 10 more fields]
: +- *Sort [id#89 ASC NULLS FIRST], false, 0
: +- Exchange hashpartitioning(id#89, 200)
: +- *Project [cast(id#67L as string) AS id#89, name#68]
: +- *Filter (isnotnull(id#67L) && isnotnull(cast(id#67L as string)))
: +- Scan ExistingRDD[id#67L,name#68,imageurl#69,status#70,optimisedformobile#71,type#72,bookingnumber#73,createdat#74,updatedat#75]
+- *Sort [cast(airportId#38 as int) ASC NULLS FIRST], false, 0
+- Exchange hashpartitioning(cast(airportId#38 as int), 200)
+- *Project [cast(airportId#18L as string) AS airportId#38, countryName#24, cityName#23, airportName#22]
+- *Filter (isnotnull(airportId#18L) && isnotnull(cast(airportId#18L as string)))
+- Scan ExistingRDD[airportId#18L,cityId#19L,countryId#20L,airportCode#21,airportName#22,cityName#23,countryName#24]

at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.errors.package$.attachTree(package.scala:56)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.exchange.ShuffleExchange.doExecute(ShuffleExchange.scala:115)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:117)
... 45 more
Caused by: org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.errors.package$TreeNodeException: execute, tree:
Exchange rangepartitioning(key#250 ASC NULLS FIRST, querydatetime#101 ASC NULLS FIRST, 200)
+- *Project [key#250 AS master_key#588, querydatetime#101 AS master_querydatetime#589, Id#180, QueryTaskId#181, QueryOriginPlace#182, queryoutbounddate#334, queryinbounddate#375, QueryCabinClass#185, QueryCurrency#186, Agent#187, QuoteAgeInMinutes#188, Price#189, OutboundLegId#190, InboundLegId#191, outdeparture#416, outarrival#457, OutDuration#194, OutJourneyMode#195, OutStops#196, OutCarriers#197, OutOperatingCarriers#198, NumberOutStops#199, NumberOutCarriers#200, NumberOutOperatingCarriers#201, ... 19 more fields]
+- *BroadcastHashJoin [key#250, querydatetime#101], [key#590, querydatetime#213], LeftOuter, BuildRight
:- *Project [key#250, querydatetime#101]
: +- BroadcastNestedLoopJoin BuildRight, Cross
: :- Generate explode(pythonUDF0#1633), false, false, [querydatetime#101]
: : +- BatchEvalPython [generate_date_series(start#94, stop#95)], [start#94, stop#95, pythonUDF0#1633]
: : +- Scan ExistingRDD[start#94,stop#95]
: +- BroadcastExchange IdentityBroadcastMode
: +- *HashAggregate(keys=[key#250], functions=[], output=[key#250])
: +- *HashAggregate(keys=[key#250], functions=[], output=[key#250])
: +- *Sample 0.0, 0.001, false, 7736333241016522154
: +- *GlobalLimit 5000000
: +- Exchange SinglePartition
: +- *LocalLimit 5000000
: +- *Project [concat(outboundlegid#190, -, inboundlegid#191, -, agent#187) AS key#250]
: +- *SortMergeJoin [querydestinationplace#212], [cast(airportId#38 as int)], Inner
: :- *Sort [querydestinationplace#212 ASC NULLS FIRST], false, 0
: : +- Exchange hashpartitioning(querydestinationplace#212, 200)
: : +- *Project [Agent#187, OutboundLegId#190, InboundLegId#191, querydestinationplace#212]
: : +- *SortMergeJoin [agent#187], [id#89], Inner
: : :- *Sort [agent#187 ASC NULLS FIRST], false, 0
: : : +- Exchange hashpartitioning(agent#187, 200)
: : : +- *Project [Agent#187, OutboundLegId#190, InboundLegId#191, querydestinationplace#212]
: : : +- *Filter (isnotnull(agent#187) && isnotnull(querydestinationplace#212))
: : : +- Scan ExistingRDD[Id#180,QueryTaskId#181,QueryOriginPlace#182,QueryOutboundDate#183,QueryInboundDate#184,QueryCabinClass#185,QueryCurrency#186,Agent#187,QuoteAgeInMinutes#188,Price#189,OutboundLegId#190,InboundLegId#191,OutDeparture#192,OutArrival#193,OutDuration#194,OutJourneyMode#195,OutStops#196,OutCarriers#197,OutOperatingCarriers#198,NumberOutStops#199,NumberOutCarriers#200,NumberOutOperatingCarriers#201,InDeparture#202,InArrival#203,... 10 more fields]
: : +- *Sort [id#89 ASC NULLS FIRST], false, 0
: : +- Exchange hashpartitioning(id#89, 200)
: : +- *Project [cast(id#67L as string) AS id#89]
: : +- *Filter (isnotnull(id#67L) && isnotnull(cast(id#67L as string)))
: : +- Scan ExistingRDD[id#67L,name#68,imageurl#69,status#70,optimisedformobile#71,type#72,bookingnumber#73,createdat#74,updatedat#75]
: +- *Sort [cast(airportId#38 as int) ASC NULLS FIRST], false, 0
: +- Exchange hashpartitioning(cast(airportId#38 as int), 200)
: +- *Project [cast(airportId#18L as string) AS airportId#38]
: +- *Filter (isnotnull(airportId#18L) && isnotnull(cast(airportId#18L as string)))
: +- Scan ExistingRDD[airportId#18L,cityId#19L,countryId#20L,airportCode#21,airportName#22,cityName#23,countryName#24]
+- BroadcastExchange HashedRelationBroadcastMode(List(input[34, string, true], input[33, date, true]))
+- *Project [Id#180, QueryTaskId#181, QueryOriginPlace#182, cast(QueryOutboundDate#183 as date) AS queryoutbounddate#334, cast(QueryInboundDate#184 as date) AS queryinbounddate#375, QueryCabinClass#185, QueryCurrency#186, Agent#187, QuoteAgeInMinutes#188, Price#189, OutboundLegId#190, InboundLegId#191, cast(unix_timestamp(OutDeparture#192, yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss, Some(Zulu)) as timestamp) AS outdeparture#416, cast(unix_timestamp(OutArrival#193, yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss, Some(Zulu)) as timestamp) AS outarrival#457, OutDuration#194, OutJourneyMode#195, OutStops#196, OutCarriers#197, OutOperatingCarriers#198, NumberOutStops#199, NumberOutCarriers#200, NumberOutOperatingCarriers#201, cast(unix_timestamp(InDeparture#202, yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss, Some(Zulu)) as timestamp) AS indeparture#498, cast(unix_timestamp(InArrival#203, yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss, Some(Zulu)) as timestamp) AS inarrival#539, ... 15 more fields]
+- *Sample 0.0, 0.001, false, 7736333241016522154
+- *GlobalLimit 5000000
+- Exchange SinglePartition
+- *LocalLimit 5000000
+- *Project [Id#180, QueryTaskId#181, QueryOriginPlace#182, QueryOutboundDate#183, QueryInboundDate#184, QueryCabinClass#185, QueryCurrency#186, Agent#187, QuoteAgeInMinutes#188, Price#189, OutboundLegId#190, InboundLegId#191, OutDeparture#192, OutArrival#193, OutDuration#194, OutJourneyMode#195, OutStops#196, OutCarriers#197, OutOperatingCarriers#198, NumberOutStops#199, NumberOutCarriers#200, NumberOutOperatingCarriers#201, InDeparture#202, InArrival#203, ... 15 more fields]
+- *SortMergeJoin [querydestinationplace#212], [cast(airportId#38 as int)], Inner
:- *Sort [querydestinationplace#212 ASC NULLS FIRST], false, 0
: +- Exchange hashpartitioning(querydestinationplace#212, 200)
: +- *Project [Id#180, QueryTaskId#181, QueryOriginPlace#182, QueryOutboundDate#183, QueryInboundDate#184, QueryCabinClass#185, QueryCurrency#186, Agent#187, QuoteAgeInMinutes#188, Price#189, OutboundLegId#190, InboundLegId#191, OutDeparture#192, OutArrival#193, OutDuration#194, OutJourneyMode#195, OutStops#196, OutCarriers#197, OutOperatingCarriers#198, NumberOutStops#199, NumberOutCarriers#200, NumberOutOperatingCarriers#201, InDeparture#202, InArrival#203, ... 11 more fields]
: +- *SortMergeJoin [Agent#187], [id#89], Inner
: :- *Sort [Agent#187 ASC NULLS FIRST], false, 0
: : +- Exchange hashpartitioning(Agent#187, 200)
: : +- *Filter (isnotnull(Agent#187) && isnotnull(querydestinationplace#212))
: : +- Scan ExistingRDD[Id#180,QueryTaskId#181,QueryOriginPlace#182,QueryOutboundDate#183,QueryInboundDate#184,QueryCabinClass#185,QueryCurrency#186,Agent#187,QuoteAgeInMinutes#188,Price#189,OutboundLegId#190,InboundLegId#191,OutDeparture#192,OutArrival#193,OutDuration#194,OutJourneyMode#195,OutStops#196,OutCarriers#197,OutOperatingCarriers#198,NumberOutStops#199,NumberOutCarriers#200,NumberOutOperatingCarriers#201,InDeparture#202,InArrival#203,... 10 more fields]
: +- *Sort [id#89 ASC NULLS FIRST], false, 0
: +- Exchange hashpartitioning(id#89, 200)
: +- *Project [cast(id#67L as string) AS id#89, name#68]
: +- *Filter (isnotnull(id#67L) && isnotnull(cast(id#67L as string)))
: +- Scan ExistingRDD[id#67L,name#68,imageurl#69,status#70,optimisedformobile#71,type#72,bookingnumber#73,createdat#74,updatedat#75]
+- *Sort [cast(airportId#38 as int) ASC NULLS FIRST], false, 0
+- Exchange hashpartitioning(cast(airportId#38 as int), 200)
+- *Project [cast(airportId#18L as string) AS airportId#38, countryName#24, cityName#23, airportName#22]
+- *Filter (isnotnull(airportId#18L) && isnotnull(cast(airportId#18L as string)))
+- Scan ExistingRDD[airportId#18L,cityId#19L,countryId#20L,airportCode#21,airportName#22,cityName#23,countryName#24]

at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.errors.package$.attachTree(package.scala:56)
... 60 more
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: Futures timed out after [300 seconds]
at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise.ready(Promise.scala:219)
at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise.result(Promise.scala:223)
at org.apache.spark.util.ThreadUtils$.awaitResult(ThreadUtils.scala:201)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.exchange.BroadcastExchangeExec.doExecuteBroadcast(BroadcastExchangeExec.scala:123)
at
```

Some googling suggests it failed because of timeout during broadcast?

My code looks like below. I think it failed near the last part, writing to parquet? But the explain logs suggests its executing the query then also?

```py
import sys
from awsglue.transforms import *
from awsglue.utils import getResolvedOptions
from pyspark.context import SparkContext
from awsglue.context import GlueContext
from awsglue.job import Job
from pyspark.sql.functions import UserDefinedFunction, udf, regexp_replace, to_timestamp, date_format, lit
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from pyspark.sql.types import ArrayType, StringType, DateType, Row
import math

## @params: [JOB_NAME]
args = getResolvedOptions(sys.argv, ['JOB_NAME'])

sc = SparkContext()
glueContext = GlueContext(sc)
spark = glueContext.spark_session
job = Job(glueContext)
job.init(args['JOB_NAME'], args)

# READ IN FLIGHTS, AIRPORTS, AGENTS TABLES
# NOTE: Bookmarks enabled for flights data catalog
airportsGDF = glueContext.create_dynamic_frame.from_catalog(database = "xxx", table_name = "airports")
airportsDF = airportsGDF.toDF().select("airportId", "countryName", "cityName", "airportName")
airportsDF = airportsDF.withColumn("airportId", airportsDF["airportId"].cast("string"))
airportsDF.createOrReplaceTempView("airports")

agentsGDF = glueContext.create_dynamic_frame.from_catalog(database = "xxx", table_name = "agents")
agentsRawDF = agentsGDF.toDF().select("id", "name")
agentsRawDF = agentsRawDF.withColumn("id", agentsRawDF["id"].cast("string"))
agentsRawDF.createOrReplaceTempView("agents")

def batch(iterable, n=1):
    l = len(iterable)
    for ndx in range(0, l, n):
        yield iterable[ndx:min(ndx + n, l)]

arr = [13301,12929,14511,9968,15280,10193,13531,13439,16122,9498,16162,17210,12728,14534,12542,13303,16716,13311,12913,11036,17471,16240,10902,15526,17294,15671,10858,17482,12071,12337,17521,12274,10032,17396,11052,9970,12917,12195,10658,17409,13078,17416,17388,12118,10438,13113,11170,14213,9762,10871,11780,12392,15518,13536,10724,14260,16747,18490,17402,10284,10982,10431,16743,12482,10497,15168,16587,15412,17106,11017,17368,13804,15461,19461,16923,9794,12795,25396,12952,15422,10101,14147,10485,12210,25336,9449,15395,13947,11893,11109,9921,9799,15253,16945,13164,10031,17002,17152,16516,13180,16451,16437,11336,13428,10182,25405,16955,10180,12191]

def generate_date_series(start, stop):
    return [start + timedelta(days=x) for x in range(0, (stop-start).days + 1)]    

spark.udf.register("generate_date_series", generate_date_series, ArrayType(DateType()))

def getInterval(num, start, stop, incr): 
    if (num is None):
        return ""

    lower = math.floor(num / incr) * incr
    upper = lower + incr
    return "(%d,%d]" % (lower, upper) 

spark.udf.register("getInterval", getInterval, StringType())
getIntervalUdf = udf(getInterval)

# CREATE DF FOR PAST 90 DAYS EXCLUDING PAST 7 DAYS
today = datetime.utcnow().date()
start = today - timedelta(days = 14) # TODO: CHANGE TO 90
sevenDaysAgo = today - timedelta(days = 7)
print(">>> Generate data frame for ", start, " to ", sevenDaysAgo, "... ")
relaventDatesDf = spark.createDataFrame([
    Row(start=start, stop=sevenDaysAgo)
])
relaventDatesDf.createOrReplaceTempView("relaventDates")

relaventDatesDf = spark.sql("SELECT explode(generate_date_series(start, stop)) AS querydatetime FROM relaventDates")
relaventDatesDf.createOrReplaceTempView("relaventDates")
print("===LOG:Dates===")
relaventDatesDf.show()

flightsGDF = glueContext.create_dynamic_frame.from_catalog(database = "xxx", table_name = "flights", transformation_ctx="flights", push_down_predicate="""
    querydatetime BETWEEN '%s' AND '%s' 
    AND querydestinationplace IN (%s)
""" % (start.strftime("%Y-%m-%d"), today.strftime("%Y-%m-%d"), ",".join(map(lambda s: str(s), arr))))

flightsDf = flightsGDF.toDF()
flightsDf.createOrReplaceTempView("flights")
print("===LOG:STARTING_QUERY===")

resultDf = spark.sql("""
    SELECT 
        f.*, 
        CONCAT(f.outboundlegid, '-', f.inboundlegid, '-', f.agent) AS key,
        countryName, cityName, airportName, a.name AS agentName
    FROM flights f
    INNER JOIN agents a
    ON f.agent = a.id
    INNER JOIN airports p
    ON f.querydestinationplace = p.airportId
    LIMIT 5000000
""") \
    .sample(False, 0.001)
resultDf.explain(True)

print("===LOG:ADDING_COLUMNS===")
resultDf = resultDf \
    .withColumn("querydatetime", resultDf["querydatetime"].cast("date")) \
    .withColumn("queryoutbounddate", resultDf["queryoutbounddate"].cast("date")) \
    .withColumn("queryinbounddate", resultDf["queryinbounddate"].cast("date")) \
    .withColumn("outdeparture", to_timestamp(resultDf["outdeparture"], "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss")) \
    .withColumn("outarrival", to_timestamp(resultDf["outarrival"], "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss")) \
    .withColumn("indeparture", to_timestamp(resultDf["indeparture"], "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss")) \
    .withColumn("inarrival", to_timestamp(resultDf["inarrival"], "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss"))

print("===LOG:WRITING_RAW===")
print("===LOG:DONE_WRITING_RAW===")
resultDf.createOrReplaceTempView("flights")

# GET DISTINCT DATASET
# distinctKeysDf = resultDf.select("outboundlegid", "inboundlegid", "agent").groupBy(["outboundlegid", "inboundlegid", "agent"])
distinctKeysDf = spark.sql("""
    SELECT key
    FROM flights
    GROUP BY key
""")
distinctKeysDf.createOrReplaceTempView("distinctKeys")

# GET RELAVENT DATES DATASET
print("===LOG:WRITING_EXPANDED===")
expandedKeyDatesDf = spark.sql("""
    SELECT key, querydatetime
    FROM relaventDates
    CROSS JOIN distinctKeys
""")

expandedKeyDatesDf.createOrReplaceTempView("expandedKeyDates")
print("===LOG:DONE_WRITING_EXPANDED===")

cleanedFlightsDf = spark.sql("""
    SELECT 
        e.key AS master_key, 
        e.querydatetime AS master_querydatetime, 
        f.*
    FROM expandedKeyDates e
    LEFT JOIN flights f
    ON e.key = f.key
    AND e.querydatetime = f.querydatetime
    ORDER BY e.key, e.querydatetime
""")
cleanedFlightsDf = cleanedFlightsDf \
    .withColumn("created_day", date_format(cleanedFlightsDf["querydatetime"], "EEEE")) \
    .withColumn("created_month", date_format(cleanedFlightsDf["querydatetime"], "yyyy-MM")) \
    .withColumn("created_month_m", date_format(cleanedFlightsDf["querydatetime"], "M").cast("int")) \
    .withColumn("created_week", date_format(cleanedFlightsDf["querydatetime"], "w").cast("int")) \
    .withColumn("out_day", date_format(cleanedFlightsDf["outdeparture"], "EEE")) \
    .withColumn("out_month", date_format(cleanedFlightsDf["outdeparture"], "yyyy-MM")) \
    .withColumn("out_month_m", date_format(cleanedFlightsDf["outdeparture"], "M").cast("int")) \
    .withColumn("out_week", date_format(cleanedFlightsDf["outdeparture"], "w").cast("int")) \
    .withColumn("out_departure_interval", getIntervalUdf(date_format(cleanedFlightsDf["outdeparture"], "H").cast("int"), lit(0), lit(24), lit(4))) \
    .withColumn("out_hour", date_format(cleanedFlightsDf["outdeparture"], "k").cast("int")) \
    .withColumn("in_day", date_format(cleanedFlightsDf["indeparture"], "EEE")) \
    .withColumn("in_month", date_format(cleanedFlightsDf["indeparture"], "yyyy-MM")) \
    .withColumn("in_month_m", date_format(cleanedFlightsDf["indeparture"], "M").cast("int")) \
    .withColumn("in_week", date_format(cleanedFlightsDf["indeparture"], "w").cast("int")) \
    .withColumn("in_departure_interval", getIntervalUdf(date_format(cleanedFlightsDf["indeparture"], "H").cast("int"), lit(0), lit(24), lit(4))) \
    .withColumn("in_hour", date_format(cleanedFlightsDf["indeparture"], "k").cast("int"))

print("===LOG:WRITING_CLEANED===")
cleanedFlightsDf \
    .repartition("countryName", "querydatetime") \
    .write \
    .mode("overwrite") \
    .partitionBy(["countryName", "querydatetime"]) \
    .parquet("s3://xxx-glue/cleanedFlights")
print("===LOG:DONE_WRITING_CLEANED===")

print("===LOG:DONE BATCH %s" % (batch))

job.commit()
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The weakest point of your code is the following:

```
LIMIT 5000000
```

if you take a careful look a the execution plan

```
: +- *GlobalLimit 5000000
: +- Exchange SinglePartition
: +- *LocalLimit 5000000
```

you'll see that the implementation uses two-step process, where partial limits are collected to a single partition. Which such larger number (`LIMIT` is simply not designed with such scenario in mind) you can easily overwhelm corresponding executor.

Additionally `LIMIT` in your code is redundant, since you follow it by `.sample(False, 0.001)`.

I'd recommend dropping the `LIMIT` clause, and adjusting fraction accordingly:

```py
result_full = spark.sql("""
    SELECT 
        f.*, 
        CONCAT(f.outboundlegid, '-', f.inboundlegid, '-', f.agent) AS key,
        countryName, cityName, airportName, a.name AS agentName
    FROM flights f
    INNER JOIN agents a
    ON f.agent = a.id
    INNER JOIN airports p
    ON f.querydestinationplace = p.airportId
""")

desired_size = (5000000 * 0.001)
fraction = desired_size / result_full .count()
assert 1 < fraction < 0  

result_sample = result_full.sample(False, fraction)
```

Additionally I'd recommend rewriting `generate_date_series`

```py
from pyspark.sql.functions import lit
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession


def generate_date_series(start, stop):
    span = (stop - start).days + 1
    return (SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()
               .range(0, span)
               .withColumn("start", lit(start))
               .selectExpr("date_add(start, id) AS querydatetime"))


(generate_date_series(start, seven_days_ago)
    .createOrReplaceTempView("relaventDates"))
```

Finally I'd strongly recommend replacing `getInterval` UDF with composition of built-in functions* (unused arguments preserved as-is):

```py
from pyspark.sql.functions import concat, floor
from pyspark.sql.functions import Column


def get_interval(num, start, stop, incr):
    assert isinstance(num, Column)

    lower = floor(num / incr).cast("integer") * incr
    upper = lower + incr
    return concat(lit("("), lower, lit(","), upper, lit(")"))
```

which could be later used as direct replacement of UDF, though it is unlikely to contribute directly to your current problems.

```py
from pyspark.sql.functions import hour

...
    .withColumn(
        "out_departure_interval",
        get_interval(hour("outdeparture"), 0, 24, 4))
```

On a side note `UDFRegistration.register` returns callable object for a couple of releases now, so you might be able to replace

```py
spark.udf.register("getInterval", getInterval, StringType())
getIntervalUdf = udf(getInterval)
```

with

```py
getIntervalUdf = spark.udf.register("getInterval", getInterval, StringType())
```

---

* You can also consider bucketing using [dedicated `window` function](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html?highlight=window#pyspark.sql.functions.window):

> Bucketize rows into one or more time windows given a timestamp specifying column. Window starts are inclusive but the window ends are exclusive, e.g. 12:05 will be in the window [12:05,12:10) but not in [12:00,12:05).

Comment: I find that sample still causes timeout for some reason thats partially why I tried limit too. The UDF suggestion is more because its better practice to use standard library functions over custom and not really performance correct?

Comment: Also for windowing, how do I use it here? I thought its more like a group by replacement? I'd like to also mention, it appears the best improvement came from adding query hint to broadcast the agents and airports table

Comment: `pyspark.sql.function.window` is not the same type of tool as window functions. It is just a convenient utility for generating temporal buckets and sliding / tumbling windows. As of UDF - the first suggestion (range) is more fundamental. With `udf` (` explode(generate_date(...))`) has no way to understand the data and it's amount. The remaining udf-related suggestions don't address timeout directly, but rather overall overhead of moving things between contexts - if it wasn't clear, I am sorry - it was just too obvious performance killer to be not addressed.

Answer (score 1):

It does look like a timed out broadcast join. The default timeout is 300 seconds, and you can start by increasing it to hours

```
spark.conf.set("spark.sql.broadcastTimeout", 7200)
```

Now, if it really takes hours to broadcast, sending this much data to all nodes is not a good idea, and you might want to disable broadcast joins

```
spark.conf.set("spark.sql.autoBroadcastJoinThreshold", -1)
```

or fine tune the code to avoid confusion on the query planner side.

Answer (score -1):

Use glueContext.write_from_options() to write data

Comment: The same error occurs. Is this supposed to make a difference in how the data is processed?

Comment: Glue write methods are optimized for Glue environment and don't have 300s timeout. So if you think timeout is during write, I would suggest to use Glue API.